# Translation of わき in this sentence

Tags: translation, kana-usage

I'm reading a beginner book with short stories and simple sentences. I'm having trouble understanding the translation of this sentence.

In the story a girl is walking down the street and then:

> 歩道のわきにタンポポがたくさんさいています。

I understand that:

歩道 - sidewalk
の - possessive particle
わき - ?
に - location particle
タンポポ - dandelion
が - subject particle?
たくさん - lots
さいています - blooming (from context)

From this, I understand that are lots of dandelions blooming 'on someplace' on the sidewalk. My problem is with the わき part, I did find the word 脇 (near, by), but my dictionary doesn't says that it is usually written in kana alone.

Comment: The use of kanji is not required even if available.

Comment: わき here means "side".  I'm not answering though because I don't feel qualified to speak on the topic of why (or why not) use kanji in a particular situation.  I think a native speaker can probably much better address that.

Comment: Don't trust the dictionary's "Usually written using kana alone" too much. Everything has a possibility of being written in kana alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > 歩道のわきにタンポポがたくさんさいています。
>
> I understand that:
> 歩道 - sidewalk　の- possessive particle
> わき - ?　に - location particle
> My problem is with the わき part, I did find the word 脇 (near, by), but my dictionary doesn't says that it is usually written in kana alone.

Generally, many of us prefer わき in *hiragana*, but it's the writer's choice.
わき alone can't function as anything in a sentence, but together with に, わきに describes a detail.

わき itself is 'side', but with the help of に, わきに means 'by/near'.
Here we have 歩道の to modify わき, so it's saying "at the side of the sidewalk" (By the sidewalk).